# Using ContentStringFormat property with TextBlock in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple ControlTemplate for buttons which creates a link-like look and feel for them:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="LinkTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works fine, but the problem arises when I want to use ContentStringFormat property to format buttons' contents. Since TextBlock doesn't have ContentStringFormat property I can't use template binding.

I also tried using StringFormat when binding button's content, but it seems to be ignored and original content text is passed to TextBlock in template binding.

I guess I could use value converted and pass ContentStringFormat to it as parameter, but it doesn't feel right.

Is there a way to do this using purely XAML or should I just use value converter?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't any idea of what is ContentStringFormat's usage, but you can use ContentPresenter instead of TextBlock to use this property.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" /> This will generate the TextBlock for you and you can use an implicit style if need be to set properties on the TextBlock that don't exist on ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find docs for "ContentStringFormat" so I may be missing something trivial here.

How about using Fil Forte's [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) within the ControlTemplate so that the Run could be formatted. [Lubo Blagoev](http://www.blagoev.com/Blog/post/Building-a-WPF-LinkLabel-control.aspx) has created a control which does just that.